# How can I create a partial with named arguments supplied in a dictionary?

Tags: python

Say I have a lambda function `foo`:

```
foo = lambda x,y,z: return x + y + z
```

and a dictionary:

```
args = {"y":2, "z":3}
```

How do I create a partial with `foo` and `args` e.g.

```
my_partial = partial(foo, args)
```

such that I can call it with the one remaining argument?

```
my_partial(1) == 6
```

Comment: Are you expecting to call `partial(foo, {"x": 1, "y": 3})`.  Are you expecting the resulting partial function to take positional arguments, or either positional or keyword arguments?

Comment: `partial(foo, **args)`…‽

Comment: A `lambda` can’t contain a `return` FWIW…